# Can I check the content of service registry in Istio?

Tags: istio

I started to learn about the implementation of Istio upon ｍｕｌti-clusters recently. There are two ways, one is [using one control plane to monitor multi-clusters](https://www.revolgy.com/blog/istio-multi-cluster-federation-and-hybrid-cloud), the other one is [deploying a control plane in each cluster and let them communicate with each other](https://github.com/danehans/federated-istio).

If I understand the concept of service registry correctly, it is used for service discovery in Istio. Is there anyway to check or monitor which services are registered in the service registry?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
istioctl proxy-status
```

check https://istio.io/docs/reference/commands/istioctl/#istioctl-proxy-status for more info